# Variable in do_shortcode to build google map does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on wordpress, using two plugins - one to manage custom post types and meta fields, and another one to display google maps with a shortcode. I try to get the address from a custom field, store it into a variable and then use it with do_shortcode:

```
<?php $address = get_cfc_field('infos', 'anschrift'); 
      $address1 = 'Auenstraße 29 80469 München';

      // Same output in html for these two...
      echo $address;
      echo $address1;

      // But this one only works with $address1
      echo do_shortcode( '[display_map address="'.$address1.'"]' );
?>
```

There are two variables for testing. Both variables give me the same output when echoed. So get_cfc_field seems to work fine.

But the Shortcode works only with $address1, with $address the map won't display the location. I already tried to strip_tags and esc_html but that did not make any difference.

What am I overlooking?

Comment: Just echoing the variables does not tell, whether the variables are equal. Try, for example, `var_dump()` to see the contents of the variables in more detail.

Comment: What did it return `var_dump($address)` ?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm living in another time zone and just got up ;) I'll try it out as soon as I had some coffee

Comment: @Alani, okay have a nice coffee. :)

Comment: Both examples give me the same result on var_dump which is string(29) "Auenstraße 29 80469 Muenchen" @Milap

Comment: I guess it has something to do with timing. Perhaps the map loads when the variable is not retrieved yet.. that's the only explanation I can imagine...

Comment: @Alani, if you think timing is the problem, try to call `do_shortcode` in `setTimeout` JavaScript function.

Comment: Ahh! I figured it out - I had to update the api key for google maps! Today nothing worked and that was strange because yesterday I could load the map with address1. Interesting that the api did work sporadically yesterday...

Answer (score 0):

The code as posted was fine, my problem was an invalid api key for the google maps plugin I used...

Interesting and irritating is only the fact, that the api responded sporadically shortly after I installed the plugin. (with address 1 only).

So this actually works as expected:

```
<?php $address = get_cfc_field('infos', 'anschrift');                                                     
        echo do_shortcode( '[display_map address="'.$address.'"]' );
?>
```